# Gallery with CursorAdapter

Tags: android

I am trying to use the Gallery View with `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Just I set the adapter for Gallery, Like:

```
gallery.setAdapter(customizedSimpleCursorAdapter);
```

The problem is, For a single View, only one image is displayed. The adapter generates the new View for every images.

In other case I tried with `BaseAdapter`. But in `BaseAdapter` we dont have overridden methods like `swapCursor()`. I need to use this method. And also the image starts to displayed from center of the view. I need to get it starts from Left Corner.

In above, I checked with that two cases. If your suggestion is related to anyone of this, That will really helpful. Thank you

This is the BaseAdapter which I used:

public static class CustomizedBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
        private Context cont;

        public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
            cont = c;
     }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ImageView image = new ImageView(cont);
       image.setImageDrawable(drawableImage);



                   return image;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah sure, i have shared above. The second Choice with BaseAdapter.

Comment: What's `drawableImage`? Why aren't you changing the drawable of the ImageView each time? I mean, the idea of the `getView` method is that, using the position parameter, you change the view accordingly.

Comment: @Cristian : Oh i am sorry there i used other integer array like 'imageContainer(position);'